# What is the simplest way to download file in PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, file-access, built-in

I need to download an image from some URL to my server. However, my server's config disallowed me to do it this way:

```
getimagesize( $file );
```

Because, it generate error:

```
Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in somefile.php  on line 10
```

So, is there another way I can use that doesn't require external library?

Ok, I solved it with solution from OIS:

```
$filename = '/tmp/'.md5($file);
$ch = curl_init($file);
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$ext = getimagesize( $filename );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible unless you modify the server configuration

Answer (score -1):

If file access to URLs is disabled on your server, you can't load any content from external URLs. That's the purpose of that configuration.

On a server where it's not disabled, file_get_contents($url) is the easiest way to fetch most files.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following to download the file into `$imgdata`.  You can then save it to a file and get its image size.  You can probably remove the file saving step with a bit of work to make it faster.

```
$imgdata = get_file_contents($url);
file_put_contents($filename, $imgdata);
getimagesize( $filename );
```

Comment: This doesn't work because of server config. Also, your code will produce fatal error.